# getting error using <sec:authorize> tag

Tags: jsp, spring-security

I would like to hide a column of a data table for a particular user. At the moment I've got this code:

```jsp
<sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ZTM_USER','ROLE_FOS_USER')">
    <td>
        <button class="data-table-button" onclick="getUserRequestedLeaveDetails(${leaveXUserDos.requestId})">
            Edit
        </button>
    </td>
</sec:authorize>
```

But this gives me an error:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>       - Syntax error on token "}", ( expected
>       - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete
>       Arguments
>       - Missing semicolon

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you give it a try after removing onclick="getUserRequestedLeaveDetails(${leaveXUserDos.requestId})">, just want to see if its the issue with authorize tag or something else

Comment: Thank you for Reply But still have same problem ...

Comment: can you please provde the complete exception stacktrace ?

Comment: Getting Multiple annotations found at this line: Error in JSP page